# Can there is way two encrypt data with one key and decrypt with two key?

Tags: java, mobile, cypher, password-encryption

I have to make encryption on client side with on key and that will be saved on server, but in case of forgotten key from user i will use public key to decrypt data, It can be hint question answer

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that you want 2 keys for decrypting, one held by the user, one held by you. While there are ways of achieving this, I'm not sure it's a good idea from a security perspective, though that depends on your exact circumstances of course. Why exactly do you need to have a key?

Comment: So you mean the anyone can decrypt the information using another key while the user thinks only he has the key?

Comment: i need to use in case of forgotten passward. maybe we can use hint question answer to decrypt it if user says i don't reminds its password key

Comment: in other words, have it encrypted two times (separately), one with each password (but "use public key to decrypt"  will be not so good - anyone can do it since public)

Comment: but if i encrypt it two times can it be data over burden?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  The basic idea is that you use a document-specific key.  For example.

1. Generate a new key-pair that is specific to the file you are encrypting.
2. Use the private key for the document to encrypt it.
3. Use the public keys for each user to encrypt the document's public key.
4. Send all of the encryptions of the document public key along with the document.
5. Each user can use hir own private key to decrypt the document key that was encrypted with hir private key, then use that key to decrypt the document.

For a more complete / rigorous explanation:

- [Pattern to allow multiple persons to decrypt a document, without sharing the encryption key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71911/pattern-to-allow-multiple-persons-to-decrypt-a-document-without-sharing-the-enc)

In fact, the document encryption doesn't need to be done using public key encryption.  A classic (strong) symmetric encryption scheme with the same key for encryption and decryption should work just as well.  (In fact better, since encryption / decryption of the document will be faster.)

There may also be other (good) ways to do this.  But the suggestion of encrypting the document multiple times, and sending all copies has the obvious problem that you effectively send (or store) N copies of the document for N people.